# Can't install taipy : ERROR : Could not build wheels for taipy-templates, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, installation, pip, pyproject.toml, taipy

I try to install taipy by creating new environment and using pip install on the step below in command prompt:

1. conda create -n taipy_env python=3.11
2. conda activate taipy_env
3. pip install taipy

but I got error message following below:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: taipy-templates
  Building wheel for taipy-templates (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for taipy-templates (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [128 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib
      creating build\lib\taipy

copying build\lib\taipy\templates\scenario-management\{{cookiecutter.__root_folder_name}}\pages\scenario_page\data_node_management.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\taipy\templates\scenario-management\{{cookiecutter.__root_folder_name}}\pages\scenario_page
      error: could not create 'build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\taipy\templates\scenario-management\{{cookiecutter.__root_folder_name}}\pages\scenario_page\data_node_management.py': No such file or directory
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for taipy-templates
Failed to build taipy-templates
ERROR: Could not build wheels for taipy-templates, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I try to fix below:

1. downgrading Python version
2. upgrading pip version
3. using lastest Pyarrow version, etc.

but I am still facing the same problem.

Comment: can you try [Installing Taipy from Source](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/installation/#installing-taipy-from-source:~:text=pip%20install%20taipy-,Installing%20Taipy%20from%20Source,-%C2%B6)

Comment: The issue is not reproducible on my end. Maybe take contact with Taipy directly

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Taipy on a MacBook Air using Python 3.11 so I do not think downgrading Python version would do the trick.

Given that the error is about not being able to create a file

> error: could not create 'build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel.\taipy\templates\scenario-management{{cookiecutter.__root_folder_name}}\pages\scenario_page\data_node_management.py'

There could be an issue with the path length. Windows has a limitation on 260 characters by default, so you could give it a try and enable long path support in Windows (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/730467/long-paths-not-working-in-windows-2019).